Обработка полученных сообщений при создании бота Telegram (tgbot-cpp)
Пытаюсь создать бота, одной из функций которого будет сохранение данных, отправленных пользователем. Проблема следующая: происходит краш программы, когда отправляется какой-либо тип данных. Например, у меня есть следующий код:
bot.getEvents().onAnyMessage([&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        if (!(message->photo.empty())) { 
            func1();
        }
        else {
            if (message->text != "") {
                func2();
            }
            else {
                if (message->video->fileId != "") {
                    func3();
                }
            }
        }      
    });

Он рабочий, но достаточно трудночитаемый и расчитан всего на несколько сценариев (а мне нужно включить проверку всех типов вложений). Когда я делаю несколько проверок параллельно (как в примере ниже), то программа крашится (например: я отправляю фото, происходит проверка "не является ли сообщение видеозаписью" и все падает).
bot.getEvents().onAnyMessage([&bot](TgBot::Message::Ptr message) {
        if (!(message->photo.empty())) { 
            func1();
        }
        
        if (message->text != "") {
            func2();
        }

        if (message->video->fileId != "") {
            func3();
        }
});

Можно ли как-то избежать краша программы в данной ситуации? Есть ли какие-то инструменты в библиотеке, отвечающие на мои запросы?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
